# GitHub Teams Polling App has stopped posting adaptive cards

Tags: windows, github, microsoft-teams

We implemented the Teams poll app from GitHub in November and it has worked very well. This Tuesday the App stopped posting the cards to chats or Meetings. You can still start the process of initiating a poll but it never shows up. We have tried reuploading the manifest file and also updating the App to a new version but this has not corrected the issue. Has anyone seen this or had a similar experience?

Comment: Could you please try once updating your MS Teams app version and check if it helps? Also could you please confirm which Teams version you are using?

Comment: We have updated the App and it did not fix the problem and this is occuring accross the entire enterprise so it is a mix of versions.

Comment: Could you please share any repro steps? Are you using any connector to post? Please share the manifest as well.

Comment: We used the default manifest for the application only modifying the support links to point to our internal documentation. This issue appears to be resolved now but any information on why it broke would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Please share any console log if you are getting. That way it will be easier to find out the root cause